# Set of vectors linearly independent

Tags: vector-spaces

Supposing $u_1,u_2,...,u_n$ a set of n vectors of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

We define the vectors $v_k=u_1+u_2+...+u_k$, as $k$ is an integer from $1$ to $n$.

How can I prove that: $(u_i)_{i\in \{1,..,n\}}$ is a set of vectors linearly independent of $\mathbb{R}^d$ only and if only the set of vectors $(v_i)_{i\in \{1,..,n\}}$ is a set of vectors linearly independent?

Comment: Note that $u_i = v_i - v_{i - 1}$ for $i > 1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It suffices to prove that the lower triangular matrix with all 1's in the lower triangle and the diagonal is invertible.

Comment: Can't use matrix because it's over the program.